# How to insert parsed data to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

How to insert parsed data in mysql, but before we need to check if record exist or not.

And I need to record item parsed description to item with parsed ID.

For example on my DB I have a lot of products with ID and another column and with empty "description" column. And I need to feel this empty column with current decsription.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql', 'database');

$site = 'http://optnow.ru/catalog';
$data = file_get_html($site);
$catalogLink = array();
$i = 0;
if(!empty($data)) {
    foreach($data->find('div.cat-name a') as $catalog) {
        $catalogLink['url'] = $catalog->href;
        $urls[] = $catalogLink;
    }
    foreach($urls as $url => $k) {
        foreach($k as $n) {
            $catalogLink = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $n . '?page=0';
            $productData = file_get_html($catalogLink);
            foreach($productData->find('.link-pv-name') as $link) {
                $productLink['url'] = $link->href;
                $productUrls[] = $productLink;
            }

        foreach($productUrls as $href) {
            $link = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $href['url'];
                $product = file_get_html($link);
                foreach($product->find('.block-d .btns-d .btn-buy') as $productId) {
                    if(!empty($productId)) {
                        $dataId = $productId->{'data-offerid'};
                    }
                }
                foreach($product->find('.description div div p') as $description) {
                    if(!empty($description)) {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO snowcore_parser_products (`description`) WHERE `remote_id` = " . $dataId . " VALUES (" . $description->plaintext . "');";

                        $sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                        print_r($sql);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: INSERT doesn't use a WHERE clause

Comment: Ok, Thanks, so how I can record description to the same item, not random?

Comment: I think that you want to insert t he remote_id as well as the plaintext? In that case, use the following:
INSERT INTO snowcore_parser_products (`description`, `remote_id`) VALUES (" . $description->plaintext . ", " . $dataId . "');

In the case that the row with the remote_is already exists, and you wisth to update it, use the following.

UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = " . $description->plaintext . " WHERE remote_id = " . $dataId . "';

Please also watch out for SQL injection.

Comment: @FrankHouweling I'm tested, it works if I put '1' for example to description(like UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = "1"; But it doens't record if I'm trying to use this - UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = " . $description->plaintext . "';